# C program not sorting array in ascending order correctly

Tags: arrays, c, sorting

I have a C program that reads a CSV file of 20 x-y coordinates. The elements are first put into a linked list, then they are put into an array where the x and y coordinate for each row is multiplied together. Once the multiplication is done, the array is then sorted into ascending order. However for some reason, when printing out the array, the values aren't sorted correctly and seem to be in a random order. I'm using qsort for this. I'm not sure why the program can't sort the values correctly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 200

typedef struct wake {
    double x, y;
    struct wake *next;
} data;

//typedef struct wake data;

void read_csv(data *head, data **tail);
void gridSearch();
void maxNode();
int num_elements(data *head);
int create_array(data *head, int num, double *array);
int compare_array(const void* a, const void* b);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int num = 0;
    struct wake* head = NULL;
    struct wake** tail = &head;
    read_csv(head, tail);
    num = num_elements(head);
    //printf("%d\n", num);
    
    double *array = malloc(num * sizeof(double));
    create_array(head,num,array);
    
}

void read_csv(data *head, data **tail) {
    // Opens the CSV datafile
    FILE *fp = fopen("data4.csv", "r");
    
    fscanf(fp, "%*[^\n]\n");
    
    char buffer[MAX];
    while (fgets(buffer, MAX, fp)) {
        data *node = malloc(sizeof(data));
        node->x = atof(strtok(buffer, ","));
        node->y = atof(strtok(NULL, ","));
        node->next = NULL;
        *tail = node;
        tail = &node->next;
        
    }
}

int num_elements(data *head) {
    struct wake *temp;
    temp = head;
    int num = 0;
    while(temp!=NULL) {
        //printf("%lf,%lf\n", temp->x,temp->y);
        num++;
        
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    return num;
}

int compare_array(const void* a, const void* b) {
    int p1 = *((double*)a);
    int p2 = *((double*)b);
    
    if (p1 < p2) { 
        return -1;
    }
    else if (p1 > p2) { 
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}

int create_array(data *head, int num, double *array) {
    struct wake *temp;
    temp = head;
    int i = 0;
    while(temp!=NULL) {
        //printf("%d: %lf %lf\n", i, temp->x, temp->y);
        array[i] = (temp->x)*(temp->y);
        i++;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    qsort(array, num, sizeof(double), compare_array);
    for (i=0; i<num; i++) {
        printf("%d: %lf\n", i, array[i]);
    }
    
    return num;
}
```

Here is the input CSV file:

```
x,y
0,0.95351
0.000413,0.953579
0.001741,0.953692
0.002695,0.953709
0.002806,0.95362
0.002277,0.953444
0.001662,0.953219
0.001404,0.953006
0.001418,0.952866
0.001181,0.952824
0.000302,0.952881
-0.001057,0.953021
-0.002364,0.953184
-0.003202,0.95329
-0.003514,0.953341
-0.003451,0.95343
-0.003154,0.953606
-0.002697,0.953808
-0.002145,0.953952
-0.001569,0.95404
```

Comment: You are comparing `int`...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
int compare (const void * a, const void * b) {
   return ( *(double*)a - *(double*)b );
}
```

also: this topic has already an answer here:
[qsort does not work for double array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11931547/qsort-does-not-work-for-double-array)

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing `int`

```
int compare_array(const void* a, const void* b) {
    double p1 = *((double*)a);
    double p2 = *((double*)b);
    
    if (p1 < p2) { 
        return -1;
    }
    else if (p1 > p2) { 
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```